# Web User Interface for Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a Web UI for Composer that I could integrate in my application so people can use composer commands through this interface instead of command line?

If not, how could I make this myself? Could I just include composer.phar in my application and use that to run composer commands with a custom made web interface?

Comment: Seems so. https://github.com/derrabus/composer-webui | https://github.com/composer-ui/composer-ui

Comment: Do these packages have composer embedded or do they rely on the composer that the user has installed?

Comment: No idea, never considered exposing composer through a web ui. I just googled it

Comment: @JimL OMG, one package is 3 years old, has seen 3 commits and is labeled "proof of concept", the other is 1 year old and has seen 5 commits. What is the intention? I would very much consider a developer unable to use the command line not a real developer - and there is already integration into IDE available, so this even doesn't need a web interface, it runs locally on the machine doing the editing, together with the GUI interface for Git.

Comment: @Sven the intention is to remove the dependency of having to install and know Composer for my application. My application has some plugins which are composer packages. I want people who use my application to be able to enable/disable plugins and to install new plugins. As these plugins already are composer packages, it would be nice if I could use Composer internally, with a nice Web UI as wrapper. This way you don't have to be a 'developer' to use my application and still be able to install/disable plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Composer is not a tool for a non-developer. Wrapping it into a GUI will not help you with all of these issues and more that are already troubling developers that ask questions here on Stackoverflow:

1. Conflicting dependencies - what if you cannot install a package because it requires another package that cannot be installed because a conflicting version already exists. Composer cannot exactly tell why it doesn't work, figuring it out is not that easy for humans.
2. Development tools need to be installed on a production machine. Things like CLI PHP, Git, SVN, Mercurial. They need to be updated (recently Git experienced a bug that allowed attacking from remote repositories.
3. The production machine need to have access to the outside world. While a HTTP server in general is accessible from outside, this usually is restricted to exposing port 80 and/or 443 for incoming connections. It is a completely different thing to allow the server to make outgoing connections to anywhere, and it makes life so much easier for attackers if this is allowed. So either you force your users to open up their firewalls or proxies (which might be impossible), or generally accept more risk using your software.
4. Even though Github and other open source hosting services are reliable, they will have downtimes - either announced and expected, but even more annoying unexpectedly. Being in the middle of a Composer update will likely render the software unusable if packages cannot be downloaded.
5. Depending on what kind of script are configured to run, or which kind of Composer plugins are installed, they also need to be maintained, and sometimes it will be impossible to update them. For example, one recent change in Composer broke an asset managing plugin, making Composer unable to run. You had to run `composer update --no-plugins`  to put the offending plugin out of the way while updating it.
6. Another topic is: Who do you trust when installing a package? If there is this nice looking plugin that a user installs, and it pulls a ton of dependencies, some of them of shady quality - who is to blame if this enables attacks? You have to be a developer to be able to asses the problem, evaluating the code you pull in. "Click here to install, and the future will be glorious" done by a regular user is no such thing.

There are a couple more stories I could tell, and they all will say to you that Composer is a development tool that should be used by a developer. It already creates several issues during regular usage, 99.9% related to external failures that need to be resolved by a knowing human - somebody clicking the GUI is not this person.

Comment: *"one recent change in Composer broke an asset managing plugin"* - nearly every change breaks that particular plugin  :P

Comment: I don't think Composer should do frontend asset management, so I don't use such plugins. Living happily ever after.

Comment: Composer wasn't *meant* to do frontend asset management. It could very well do it, but not very well via an external plugin that hacks deeply back into Composer's changing core.

Comment: But I still want non-developers to be able to download and update plugins for my application easily. These plugins are now composer packages (with a custom type). Would it be better to not use composer for my plugins then? Or would it be a idea to only use a wrapper UI for composer to install plugins and that any other packages would need to be installed through the normal command line?

Answer (score 1):

If security isn't an issue for you, you could make one yourself.  A simple one would look something like this:

```
<?php

// Pass in your composer command through a GET parameter
$command = $_GET['composer_command'];
// Replace the word "composer" since you'll most likely not have it in your    
// Apache user's PATH
$command = str_replace('composer', '', $command);
// Now we explicitly tell PHP where the composer.phar file is stored on your    
// server.  We run the command and return the response
echo shell_exec("php /path/to/composer.phar $command");

?>
```

In the above, you need to make sure the Apache (or Nginx) user has permission to execute `composer.phar`.

You'll probably want to add escape characters and other features for edge cases, but the above will take care of the most common composer commands.

Comment: Yeah I also thought of this idea, but it feels very hacky, even though security is not really an issue as it is only for administrators who already have access to the whole application. Isn't there a nicer way to accomplish something like this? By creating a composer object or something?

Comment: Do note that Composer needs a `HOME` or `COMPOSER_HOME` path variable to be set, so it usually doesn't work right away from a browser process.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes If you look at the example, the path for composer is an absolute path to its phar file

Comment: @LloydBanks https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Factory.php#L602-605

Comment: @Niets Keurentjes hmm thats unfortunate. do you know a nice way to run composer from your browser?

Comment: @Mainone You can use this method.  You just have to set the path to your `composer.phar` with the above code